# Class type for primitives in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, reflection, types, primitive

I know in Objective-C we can get a class type for an object using:

```
+ (Class)class;
```

However, if I want to get the class type for primitive types, like `int` or `short`, how do I do that?

Does something like that exist in Objective C?

In Java we can get the class types of primitives by following:
E.g.
    `Class<?> classType = short.class;`

Does anything similar exist in Objective C?

```
NSString* numStr = @"124";
```

Now I want to dynamically invoke a method (the method name is known at runtime only).
The method could take any type of numeric input like `short`, `int`, `long`, `double`, or `NSNumber`.

E.g.

```
(void) doSomethingWithInt: (int) intVal;
(void) doSomethingWithShort: (short) shortVal;
(void) doSomethingWithDouble: (double) doubleVal;
(void) doSomethingWithNSNum: (NSNumber) NSNumVal;
```

I believe `NSInvocation` can be used for invoking methods reflectively. But while setting arguments in the `NSInvocation`, object how can I properly convert the string to all the different types?

Comment: Why do you want do differentiate between the various number types? What is your _highlevel_ goal, that is: what do you want to do with this string? Usually, you only need to parse that number once and put it in an `NSNumber`. Also, have a look at the [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which is also used to correctly parse various number formats.

Comment: The goal is to create a generic invoker method which might need to invoke any kind of method with any type of parameter at runtime.

Comment: Sounds more like a "how" and not "why", or you're making a problem too generic. Anyway, you'll need to use [low-level Objective-C runtime functions (C API)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) to get the method signature to check the argument types of the receiver so you'll know whether to convert the numbers to an `int`, `long` or `double`. But the method signature won't tell you if a method wants a `NSNumber` vs. an `NSString`, it'll just tell you it wants an object. So you'd need to encode that with your value.

Comment: Instead of the C API you can also use things like [`-[NSObject methodSignatureForSelector:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsobject_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/methodSignatureForSelector:), of course. Still, you need to parse the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitives are not classes, thus you can't get their type like this. However, there's [`@encode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html) (see also the [NSHipster blog entry](http://nshipster.com/type-encodings/)) which might be of help to you, depending on what you want to do.

In Java primitives aren't classes either, but through [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) the corresponding wrapper classes are used when necessary. Objective-C doesn't do this magic for you.

To solve the usecase:
Assuming the function takes only primitive numeric values or NSNumber we can identify the right parameter type using @encoding as described in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559005/how-to-get-class-type-for-primitives-in-objective-c#comment36155075_23559005).
There is no other way to reflectively identify the exact method signature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added my usecase to the question, can you let me know how it can be achieved with objective C. ( I am  fairly new to Objective C, hence this basic question)

Comment: Based on your comments to the initial question, I have edited your answer to add details about the original usecase and marking this as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Primitives don't have classes, by definition, but you can use the [`__typeof__` keyword](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) to get the type of a primitive, even using it to declare another variable with that type:

```
int x = 10;
__typeof__(x) y = 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

> However if I want to get the class type for primitive types like int
>   or short how do I do it?

`int`, `char`, `float` etc are not a class.

However you can get its type by objective-C runtime.